# Why first draw image to java JPanel control does not work?

Tags: java, swing

When first draw image to java JPanel it does not work?

The code looks like this:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    Image myImage=null;
    boolean isFirst=true;
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
      super.paint(g);

      if(!isFirst) return;
      isFirst=false;

      g.drawImage(myImage, 350, 200, 50, 50, this);
  }

  public MyPanel() {
    myImage=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
    Panel.class.getResource("/MyImg.png"));
  }
 }
```

Here is the call MyPanel:
    public class App extends JFrame{
    public App() {
        MyPanel mp=new MyPanel();
        this.add(mp);
    }
    }

I has solved this problem.  It looks like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(myImage, 350, 200, 50, 50, this);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't override the `paint` method of a swing component. Rather, you should override the `paintComponent` method. And where is the code that makes this JPanel visible?

Comment: How to override swing paintComponent method? ths.

Comment: Read the applicable [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).